# Outlook Add-In Event Listeners

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am working on an Outlook JS add-in where I take the list of Recipient Emails (To, CC) and send it to a server and return back whether or not an email is already in that user's database on a website.

Is there an event listener that fires when a user Adds/Edits/Removes an email address from the To/CC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed is one. Look at recipientsChangedEvent in the event types on Office.context.mailbox.item [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item?view=outlook-js-preview). This was introduced as part of the requirement set 1.7.